# E-mail form in ASP not sorting form correctly

Tags: forms, email, asp-classic

I was doing a little job for a friend of mine in ASP (Since his server runs IIS) I usually script websites in PHP therefor im not that well known in ASP. Yet the job was simple so i took it on. What he wanted was a form page where he could insert and/or edit existing form elements, and a ASP page wich renders them and send the result to an e-mail. All this works great within my script. The only problem is, that it does not order the form elements as their seen on the forms html page, it is somehow mixing them. Is there any way of getting over with this problem, so it sorts them out depending on their position in the html document? My code is like this:

```
    <%
            Dim besked
            Dim beskedhtml

        for each x in Request.Form 
            if x = "submit" Then

            Elseif x = "modtager" Then

            Else
        besked = besked & x & " : " & Request.Form(x) & "" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & ""
            beskedhtml = beskedhtml & "<b>" & x & "</b>" & " : " & Request.Form(x) & "<br><br>"
            End If
        next 


Set myMail=CreateObject("CDO.Message")
myMail.Subject=Request.Form("emne")
myMail.From = "from@hej.com"
myMail.To=Request.Form("modtager")
myMail.HTMLBody=beskedhtml
myMail.TextBody=besked
myMail.Send
set myMail=nothing

    Response.Write(beskedhtml & " was send.")
    %>
```

**Edit**
I figured it out on my own.
To sort the requests you will need to iterate over it numerical using a Count() function on the request, like this:

```
    for x = 1 to Request.Form.count() 
        if Request.Form.key(x) = "submit" Then

        Elseif Request.Form.key(x) = "modtager" Then

        Else
        besked = besked & Request.Form.key(x) & " : " & Request.Form.item(x) & "" & vbCrLf & "" & vbCrLf & ""
    beskedhtml = beskedhtml & "<b>" & Request.Form.key(x) & "</b>" & " : " & Request.Form.item(x) & "<br><br>"
        End If
next
```

Then you control it with  `Request.Form.key(x)` For the form elements name and
`Request.Form.item(x)` for the value of the element.

Happy coding all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this article offers an explanation.

https://web.archive.org/web/20061026091404/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/aspfaqs/ShowFAQ.asp?FAQID=64

To get specific values you will need to retrieve them as they are needed or move them into a set of variables for later use.  Generally the latter is the more desirable approach so that input can be validated along the way.

Answer (score 0):

ASP does it's own thing. I have never been able to get it to sort... go figure.